# Почему главная страница сайта открывается на русском языке?

Tags: wordpress

Создал небольшой сайт.
Плагин polylang.
Три языка: румынский, русский и английский.
Когда создавал языки, приоритет поставил для румынского 1, русский - 2, английский - 3.
Теперь когда открывают главную, открывается версий на русском, а нужно на румынском.

Как это исправить?
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Скорее всего, активирована эта опция https://polylang.pro/doc/detect-the-browser-preferred-language/

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы, отключил опцию, и теперь открывается страница на румынском.